# C# Compute GIT Commit Hash

Tags: c#, git, sha

I'm trying to get the SHA1 commit hash for a GIT commit manually, but something isn't working correctly.

First we have the standard commit message that looks something like this:

```
tree f594b3f6d9ae291c83902f3992aa36872aa70d68

parent 0000004bf6d464667df5150b4526083886947d92

author User <foo@bar.com> 1390620460.46263 +0000
committer User <foo@bar.com> 1390620460.46263 +0000

Commit Message
```

we'll call that the 'commitMessage'

The spec says that to get the commit hash says we have to sha1:

- the string "commit"
- plus a space " "
- plus the number of bytes in the commitMessage
- plus a null byte
- plus the commitMessage

so (pseudo code obv)

`SHA1( "commit" + " " + numBytes(commitMessage) + '\0' + commitMessage );`

And here's my implementation in C#
(I'm aware this is quite clunky)

```
    var commitBody = "tree " + treeHash + "\n\n" +
                     "parent " + parentHash + "\n\n" +
                     "author User <foo@bar.com> " + date + "\n" +
                     "committer User <foo@bar.com> " + date + "\n\n" +
                     "My Commit Message\n";

    var blob = "commit " + Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(commitBody);

    // This is the string "commit " (with a space) + byte count
    var first = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blob);

    // This is just the null byte
    var second = new byte[1];
    second[0] = (byte)0;

    // This is the commitMessage
    var third = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(commitBody);

    // Merge first, second, third into bytez as a byte array
    var bytez = new byte[first.Length + second.Length + third.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, bytez, 0, first.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, bytez, first.Length, second.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(third, 0, bytez, first.Length + second.Length, third.Length);

    // Debug Print
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytez));

    // Compute the hash and print it
    var sss = SHA1.Create();
    var myssh = GetString(sss.ComputeHash(bytez));
    Console.WriteLine(myssh);
```

The hash returned is not the same as what is returned from GIT. I'm not actually expecting anyone to know how to do this, as this isn't something that is usually done, but I figured I'd ask.

Thanks for any help :D

Answer (score 1):

Every object's hash is actually the hash of "Length + ' ' + Content" - this works to prevent SHA1 hash collisions (since now you have to collide on both the SHA1 *and* the length, which is way less likely)

Comment: nitpick: I think you mean object, not blob, since this about commits

Answer (score 1):

If you are using UTF-8 characters in your strings, don't use `string.Length` to reserve bytes array. This is true if the string only contains ASCII characters, but if there is UTF-8 Characters in your string, then `.Length` will will be smaller than the actual byte size.

Since you are using `.Length` to allocate an array, that array may be to small and not all of the strings data may be copied.

I'd suggest that you use `StringBuilder` to build your string, and then use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringbuilder.ToString())` to get the data as bytes.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("commit "+ Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(commitBody));
sb.Append("\0");
sb.Append(commitBody);

var sss = SHA1.Create();
var bytez = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
var myssh = GetString(sss.ComputeHash(bytez));
Console.WriteLine(myssh);
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no blank lines after the `tree` and `parent` lines, i.e. the commit body should be:

```
tree f594b3f6d9ae291c83902f3992aa36872aa70d68
parent 0000004bf6d464667df5150b4526083886947d92
author User <foo@bar.com> 1390620460.46263 +0000
committer User <foo@bar.com> 1390620460.46263 +0000

Commit Message
```

See the original C implementation; commit_tree_extended() in [commit.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/commit.c).

Answer (score 0):

Not C#, but here's how you can calculate a git commit hash from the bash prompt:

```
commit_len=$(git cat-file commit HEAD | wc -c)
(echo -ne "commit $commit_len\0"; git cat-file commit HEAD) | sha1sum
```

Check that the hash is correct:

```
git show HEAD | grep commit
```